# AppStore approval and md5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, md5, appstore-approval

I'm using md5 from `<CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>`.

I don't use it for encryption purposes.

I know that in submitting an app to AppStore, it's asked if the app uses encryption.

Is this the case to answer yes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MD5 is not an encryption algorithm, it's a hashing algorithm. Encryption has to be reversible.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it's a technical answer to a non technical issue.

Answer (score 3):

As it is not an encyrption, you can say "No" without hesitation.

I use CC_MD5 in my projects too. I always say "No" when asked if the app uses encryption just before submitting. None of them rejected so far.