# iOS: is an MD5 hash considered "encryption" when submitting to the app store?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, encryption, md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AppStore approval and md5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296667/appstore-approval-and-md5)

When developing iPhone or iPad apps and submitting to the app store they ask whether the app "contains encryption"? For example if using HTTPS then you need to get an ERN. Makes sense.

However, if an app uses unencrypted HTTP but transmits an MD5 hash of the users password, would that be considered "encryption"?

An MD5 is a one way hashing function. The source data is not recoverable from the hashed data so I'm just not sure whether it's technically considered "encryption" or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, MD5 is not encryption, as encryption must be reversible. MD5 is a hashing algorithm.